# jQuery '.click(callback)' prevents the default event

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events, event-propagation

I'm trying to **prevent the double-clicking of a form button**, disabling the element for some seconds.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="password" />
    <button class="myButton" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>


var that = this;
this.element = $(".myButton");
this.element.click(function(e) {
    this.element.prop("disabled", true);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        that.element.prop("disabled", false);
    }, 2000);
});
```

It succeeds in enabling/disabling, but the use of `.click()` function prevents (automatically? O_o) the propagation of the event, and the page **doesn't follow the link** in the form *action* attribute.

***Note*** I'm trying to add the behaviour to a form button that **was previously working perfectly** (POSTing to the *aciton* link).
Also the enabling/disabling works perfectly (regardless eventual errors that I could have made in the adaption of the code above).

PS - Any solution must be cross-browser and compatible with IE8.

Comment: Where is the other click handler?  The one that isn't being invoked.  This example shows the disabling/enabling, but doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Comment: `this` is referring to window inside setTimeout callback, use `that`

Comment: following your edit, what code are you currently using??? Why don't you post the relevant one instead of editing your question with new code on each comment/answer?

Comment: `var that = this;`  Is this *inside* a function block?

Comment: @A.Wolff I usually prefer to not expose directly my code with the naming I'm using and prefer to present a sample.
@RocketHazmat Yes, it is. The function is the definition of an object that I will extend later (via `.prototype = {...}`).

Comment: Maybe the form isn't submitting because its submit button is `disabled`?  I'm not sure if that's the issue here or not.  You can try to instead bind to the `<form>`'s `onsubmit` event, see if that works.

Comment: I don't get it, why would doubleclicks be an issue, the form only submits and reloads the page once anyway ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ya on FF IIRC, the fix could be to just set disabled in a timeout with delay 0 because of stack event

Comment: @RocketHazmat I think you probably found the reason. I'll make a quick try!

Comment: @adeneo if the user double click it will be fast enough to retrigger the post in a second time (and is what I want to avoid).

Comment: That's an issue that doesn't really exists in the wild, noone does this sorta thing. Forms submit fast and users are generally aware of how they work, but whatever floats your goat.

Comment: And I'm not sure that's even true, the form is submitted when it reloads the page, clicking the button fast multiple times shouldn't trigger a submit more than once, as long as it's the native form submit.

Comment: @adeneo I guess this is related more to every single browser implementation; if it is real I should care of checking every single browser behaviour. Anyway I've been asked to implement it (don't know if it is cause of something happened or just premature optimisation) and I _must_ do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By disabling the button, you are preventing the post action from taking place. So what you would want to do is disable the form and then use javascript call to actually submit the form.  That could look like this:

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
    $button = $(this);
    $button.attr('disabled', true);
    $button.closest('form').submit();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $button.attr('disabled', false);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This will work, but if he is trying to submit a ajax form this isn't the best solution. Best would be disable the button in Button click or ajax beforeSend and reenable it in onComplete.

Comment: @PauloSegundo - if he was trying to do ajax, he wouldn't have this issue to begin with.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, as also _Rocket Hazmat_ had suggested. Your code (regardless the `beforeSend`/`onComplete` argument) is working perfectly! Thanks Mike :)